# .NET coding practices and code maintenance

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an ASP.NET webpage where a user can generate 5 different types of reports.

I was wondering if it is acceptable coding practice to create 5 different .aspx pages with 5 different gridViews.

I know I could use just one .aspx page and generate all 5 gridviews dynamically in the server code, but it seems that from a code maintenance point of view, it would be better to separate the various reports into their own page.

I know this might create some code duplication.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't suppose it's possible for you to use a proper reporting tool like SSRS?

Comment: DRY (don't repeat yourself) is a rule-of-thumb and not an absolute. You need to decide if the trade-offs for either approach are worth it.

Comment: I would say its very dependant on just how much code duplication there will be, if the only duplication is wiring up a couple of button click events then 5 pages may be a simpler solution.  Whatever approach you take try to refactor any common functionality into appropriate common classes.  There is a lot to be said for what ever makes things simplest in the big picture (if you see what I mean ;))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to duplicate code even if you create multiple pages for your reports. You could just create a business object that contains the code that's shared among the reports and then the pages would simply implement the specific details.

I'd probably create separate pages for each report - it's easier to maintain, plus reports have a habit of evolving over time.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you create one user control and make use of that control in the page that would be good option.

Answer (score 3):

I would just use inheritance and a single page/grid. Then, use polymorphism for any customizations to the page and grid. For example, you could have a base report class, which your 5 different reports inherit from, and specify exactly what changes between reports.

Answer (score 3):

You could create one aspx and five UserControls. You could have report filters in the aspx that the individual reports can utilise. i.e. Date Ranges, etc.

You could load different UserControls based on QueryString parameters etc.